# Laravel 4.2 union

Tags: php, laravel, union

For the following request:

```
$gamer_id = DB::table('users_relations')->select('gamer_id')->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->first();
$test_id = DB::table('users_relations')->select('gamer_id')->where('user_id', '=', 2)->first();
$results = $gamer_id->union($test_id)->get(); 

dd($results);
```

I have the error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException

Call to undefined method stdClass::union()
```

Any thought about that ?
Thank you!

P.S. Documentation -−> http://laravel.com/docs/queries#unions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `first()`, you `get()` and return the first result. `$gamer_id` is no longer a query builder as a result, so it lacks the union function. Instead, use the query modifier `take(1)`.

```
$gamer_id = DB::table('users_relations')
  ->select('gamer_id')
  ->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
  ->take(1);
$test_id = DB::table('users_relations')
  ->select('gamer_id')
  ->where('user_id', '=', 2)
  ->take(1);
$results = $gamer_id->union($test_id)->get();
```

Comment: Yes, i just saw that... Thank you ceejayoz