# Call to undefined method stdClass::union()

Tags: mysql, laravel, union, fatal-error, stdclass

I need to join multiple queries together. Trying to do it using union. But Laravel 5 is throwing this error.

> Fatal error Exception. Call to undefined method `stdClass::union()`

I googled it, but as I am new to it so Can't find solution to problem. My controller code is below.

I am trying to pass  an array `$nows` in view to populate my table rows.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
class NervousController extends Controller {

    public function view()
    {
        return view('nervous/view');
    }

    public function motorTable()
    {
        $user = DB::table('users')->where('name', 'alpha')->first();
        $nows = DB::table('patients')->where('name', 'Beta')->first()->union($user)->get();
        return view('nervous/motor')->with('data', $nows);
    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24166337/laravel-4-2-union

Comment: i have used the query modifier 'take(1)'  still issue remains

Comment: because `first` executes the query and returns you a stdClass object or null.

Comment: what do you mean by   first() returns  stdClass object? Shoudl i edit my database or edit the query?  I am new to it

Comment: instead of `first()` use `take(1)`

Comment: Would you post the relationship between users and patients? Is there a particular reason you're avoiding Eloquent?